# Facebook Like button posts my webhost thumbnail and URL on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

So, I've run my url through the facebook debugger and everything comes out right.  if i post my url in a status, the correct thumbnail and description comes up.  However, the like button on my site results in my web host url and thumbnail showing on facebook.
My url is adammoritzmusic.com

My `iframe` code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fadammoritzmusic.com&amp;width=200&amp;height=35&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

help?

Answer (score 0):

There's **3 Solutions You can follow**:

**#1**

Use `http://adammoritzmusic.com/Home.html` (without `https`) because when you `adammoritzmusic.com` Facebook will use your `index.html` which redirects to `Home.html`

(Facebook Like button has a bug, the same domain has two different counts of likes one for `http` and the other for `https`)

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fadammoritzmusic.com/Home.html&amp;width=200&amp;height=35&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**#2**

Use `Index.html` instead of `home.html` or just use `.htaccess` file to make `home.html` as your default index file:

```
DirectoryIndex Home.html
```

**#3**

Create a Facebook fan page, this would the fastest and easiest solution.